# setState causing re-rendering while updating styles on mouseMove event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events

I am trying to update styles of a component using `setState` on a `mouseMove` event. The problem is the event is reset because of re-render on state update. How can I update state in sync without causing an event reset.

Link to the code:

[Make an image draggable inside a container (panning) in react. setState causing trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61438292/make-an-image-draggable-inside-a-container-panning-in-react-setstate-causing)

Comment: Try using useRef and useEffect on the listened element

Comment: Can u explain in detail please..